# Was Damar's comment to Leeta in DS9 S06E06 ad-libbed by the actor?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In episode S06E06 of DS9 ([Sacrifice of Angels](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sacrifice_of_Angels_(episode))), several members of the resistance cell (Kira, Jake, Quark, & Leeta) are sitting around a table discussing the situation when Damar walks in and "detains them for questioning". Quark walked away just before Damar arrived, but Kira mentions to the Jake and Leeta "it'll be alright." Damar then snidely commented that they had nothing to hide. As Leeta stood up, her chest approximately a foot away from Damar's face, he made the following risque comment:

> *You* certainly don't.

For those who don't know, Leeta is an attractive & busty woman, and in-universe, many Cardassians have a fondness for Bajoran women. However, the off-handed nature of the comment and his smirk afterward led me to wonder if the line was written that way or the actor was doing a little improv.

**Note:** At this point in his character development, Damar was still very strait-laced & serious. He didn't make jokes or quips, therefore making his comment to Leeta seem out of character.

**Was this line in the script or was it ad-libbed by actor Casey Biggs?**

Comment: Is there a history of ad-libbing on this show? This is confusing to me why you would think this.

Comment: I hope not! Hostile work environment!

Comment: @1252748 - a history of ad-libbing is irrelevant. Given any scene in any show, an ad-libbed line or delivery can make it on-screen if the director likes it.

Comment: I could go through any scene in any show in the history of tv and movie sci-fi and post on SF&F SE "Is this line ad-libbed, or was it in the script?" ... "What about _this_ one?". Therefore a history of ad-libbing on this series makes this question slightly interesting. Otherwise, not as much; it's just very random and pointless.

Comment: @1252748 - the question is neither random nor pointless. At this point in Damar's character arc, he was still very much a serious soldier. He was not given to jokes or quips. Overall, the comment seemed more like something the actor might've slipped in himself. I've updated the question to point that out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be an ad-libbed line according to the script I found [here](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/530.txt).

Here's the relevant line from the script

```
                DAMAR 
        Of course it will. You have 
        nothing to hide, do you?
            (looking at Leeta) 
        You certainly don't.

Kira slowly gets up to accompany Damar. Jake and Leeta 
follow, escorted by the soldiers and a very 
self-satisfied Damar.
```